# Outlook 2010: Change message zoom with the keyboard

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2010

I try to use my computer while touching the mouse as little as possible, using the keyboard for as many actions that I can.

I'm now using Outlook 2010 on Windows 7. I'm opening a message and the text is too small for me to read. Two questions:

1. How can I change the zoom with the keyboard? I can do it with the mouse by pressing ctrl and using the scrollwheel, but I want a way to do it with the keyboard.
2. Is there a way to get all messages to open with 150% zoom by default?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't.
2. I can recommend the free [Quick Tweaks](https://www.reliefjet.com/Quicks/Features/QuickTweaks) add-in developed by my company. After installing Quicks, just set the "Default zoom for message windows" to 150% and forget it.